# Jupyter Notebook different ways to display out

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

There seems to be 3 ways to display output in Jupyter:

1. By using `print`
2. By using `display`
3. By just writing the variable name

What is the exact difference, especially between number 2 and 3?

Comment: They are incomparable. `IPython.display` can: markdown, HTML, video, images, audio ... a lot! And you can redefine it

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used `display`, but it looks like it provides a lot of controls.  `print`, of course, is the standard Python function, with its own possible parameters.

But lets look at a simple `numpy` array in Ipython console session:

Simply giving the name - the default `out`:

```
In [164]: arr
Out[164]: array(['a', 'bcd', 'ef'], dtype='<U3')
```

This is the same as the `repr` output for this object:

```
In [165]: repr(arr)
Out[165]: "array(['a', 'bcd', 'ef'], dtype='<U3')"
In [166]: print(repr(arr))
array(['a', 'bcd', 'ef'], dtype='<U3')
```

Looks like the default `display` is the same:

```
In [167]: display(arr)
array(['a', 'bcd', 'ef'], dtype='<U3')
```

`print` on the other hand shows, as a default, the `str` of the object:

```
In [168]: str(arr)
Out[168]: "['a' 'bcd' 'ef']"
In [169]: print(arr)
['a' 'bcd' 'ef']
```

So at least for a simple case like this the key difference is between the `repr` and `str` of the object.  Another difference is which actions produce an `Out`, and which don't.  `Out[164]` is an array.  `Out[165]` (and 168) are strings. `print` and `display` display, but don't put anything on the `Out` list (in other words they return `None`).

`display` can return a 'display' object, but I won't get into that here.  You can read the docs as well as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my understanding:

1. `print` is just the native print function that Python provides, as defined here in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

   in short, it'll spit out a text representation of whatever you put in, and put that in the cell's output. but that's it; it *only* does text.
2. `display` is IPython's special-sauce function (see [the `ipython` docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display)). it's a lot like `print`, in that 1. you put stuff in and 2. it'll put a representation of the stuff in the cell's output.

   The difference from `print` is that `display` can make representations that are WAY more than "just text" (as @Alex Yu noted, "markdown, HTML, video, images, audio", etc.). All the different types of media that `display` can support are described in the IPython docs linked above as well.
3. "just writing the variable name", specifically on the *last line* of a cell, will **just call `display` on that variable name under the hood**. I.e., it's just a short-hand convenience. (Though I can't find any docs confirming this; any links appreciated!)

Comment: I think this is mostly correct, but why is it that `display` shows quotes around strings while `print` and rich values with `display` don't?

Comment: @Nick Hmm interesting find! that sounds like `display` is calling `__repl__` to get a string representation, while `print` is just calling `__str__`? not positive though, I'd have to do some tests to confirm.

Comment: it’s `__repr__`, not `__repl__`